# I am having trouble in connecting Laravel 8 with elastic search

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

The elastic search version is 8.8. When I dont run elastic server then the error is:
[image]

After successfully running the elastic server i got this error in my project:
[image]

the code I am using to make connection is:
`$client = ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts(['http://localhost:9200'])->build();`
`$response = $client->info();`
`return $response['version']['number'];`

my database config is:

```
'elasticsearch' => [
            'driver' => 'elasticsearch',
        'hosts' => [
            [
                'host' => env('ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS', 'http://localhost'),
                'port' => env('ELASTICSEARCH_PORT', 9200),
                'scheme' => env('ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME', 'http'),
                'user' => env('ELASTICSEARCH_USER'),
                'pass' => env('ELASTICSEARCH_PASS'),
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Kindly help regarding this. For reference I am sharing the package I am using:
https://packagist.org/packages/elasticsearch/elasticsearch

I have tried different version like elastic 7.0.0, 7.10, 8.0.0 and different Laravel versions as well but still no success.

Comment: When running elasticsearch, if you go to your browser at `http://localhost:9200` does it work and does it show the expected ES metadata (e.g. version tagline etc)

Comment: Yes it is show metadata:


{
  "name" : "DESKTOP-QI6H2EA",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "62HwElBPQRCc25HCh-oauQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.0.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "zip",
    "build_hash" : "b7e28a7",
    "build_date" : "2019-04-05T22:55:32.697037Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.0.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.7.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}